# Q: import javax.annotation.Generated

Tags: java, eclipse

The error im getting when importing the pacage is : The pacage javax.annotation is not accesible.
The error whem im compiling since i cant use Generated down in the code is :
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer

java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users"NAME".p2\pool\plugins\es.ucm.gaia.colibristudio.LibraryPool_1.0.0\lib\databaseconnector\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jboss.transaction.api.1.1.spec: Invalid module name: '1' is not a Java identifie

The code is :

```
 
import jcolibri.cbraplications.StandardCBRApplication;
import jcolibri.cbrcore.CBRCase;
import jcolibri.cbrcore.CBRCaseBase;
import jcolibri.cbrcore.CBRQuery;
import jcolibri.cbrcore.Connector;
import jcolibri.exception.ExecutionException;
import jcolibri.exception.InitializingException;
import jcolibri.method.retrieve.NNretrieval.NNConfig;
 
import javax.annotation.Generated;  //This is where im getting the error and 
                                   //every Generated after does not work
import representation.CaseDescription;
import representation.CaseSolution;
import jcolibri.method.retrieve.NNretrieval.NNConfig;
import jcolibri.cbrcore.Attribute;
import jcolibri.method.retrieve.RetrievalResult;
import jcolibri.method.retrieve.NNretrieval.NNScoringMethod;
import jcolibri.method.retrieve.selection.SelectCases;
import java.util.Collection;
 
public class CBRApplication implements StandardCBRApplication {
 
    @Generated(value = { "ColibriStudio" })
    Connector connector;
   
    @Generated(value = { "ColibriStudio" })
    CBRCaseBase casebase;
 
 
 
    //******************************************************************/
    // Configuration
    //******************************************************************/
 
    @Override
    public void configure() throws ExecutionException {
        try{
            configureConnector();
            configureCaseBase();
        } catch (Exception e){
            throw new ExecutionException(e);
        }
    }
 
    /** Configures the connector */
    @Generated(value = { "CS-PTConector" })
    private void configureConnector() throws InitializingException{
        connector = new jcolibri.connector.PlainTextConnector();
        connector.initFromXMLfile(jcolibri.util.FileIO.findFile("config/plainTextConnectorConfig.xml"));
    }
 
    /** Configures the case base */
    @Generated(value = { "CS-CaseManager" })   
    private void configureCaseBase() throws InitializingException{
        casebase = new jcolibri.casebase.LinearCaseBase();
    }
 
    //******************************************************************/
    // Similarity
    //******************************************************************/
   
    /** Configures the similarity */
    @Generated(value = { "CS-Similarity" })
    private NNConfig getSimilarityConfig() {
        NNConfig simConfig = new NNConfig();
        simConfig.setDescriptionSimFunction(new jcolibri.method.retrieve.NNretrieval.similarity.global.Average());
        Attribute attribute0 = new Attribute("HolidayType", CaseDescription.class);
        simConfig.addMapping(attribute0, new jcolibri.method.retrieve.NNretrieval.similarity.local.Equal());
        simConfig.setWeight(attribute0, 1.00);
        Attribute attribute1 = new Attribute("NumberOfPersons", CaseDescription.class);
        simConfig.addMapping(attribute1, new jcolibri.method.retrieve.NNretrieval.similarity.local.Equal());
        simConfig.setWeight(attribute1, 1.00);
        Attribute attribute2 = new Attribute("Region", CaseDescription.class);
        simConfig.addMapping(attribute2, new jcolibri.method.retrieve.NNretrieval.similarity.local.Equal());
        simConfig.setWeight(attribute2, 1.00);
        Attribute attribute3 = new Attribute("Transportation", CaseDescription.class);
        simConfig.addMapping(attribute3, new jcolibri.method.retrieve.NNretrieval.similarity.local.Equal());
        simConfig.setWeight(attribute3, 1.00);
        Attribute attribute4 = new Attribute("Duration", CaseDescription.class);
        simConfig.addMapping(attribute4, new jcolibri.method.retrieve.NNretrieval.similarity.local.Equal());
        simConfig.setWeight(attribute4, 1.00);
        Attribute attribute5 = new Attribute("Season", CaseDescription.class);
        simConfig.addMapping(attribute5, new jcolibri.method.retrieve.NNretrieval.similarity.local.Equal());
        simConfig.setWeight(attribute5, 1.00);
        Attribute attribute6 = new Attribute("Accommodation", CaseDescription.class);
        simConfig.addMapping(attribute6, new jcolibri.method.retrieve.NNretrieval.similarity.local.Equal());
        simConfig.setWeight(attribute6, 1.00);
        return simConfig;
    }
 
    //******************************************************************/
    // Methods
    //******************************************************************/
   
 
    @Generated(value = { "ColibriStudio" })
    @Override
    public CBRCaseBase preCycle() throws ExecutionException {
        casebase.init(connector);
        return casebase;
    }
       
    @Generated(value = { "ColibriStudio" })
    @Override
    public void cycle(CBRQuery query) throws ExecutionException {
        NNConfig simConfig = getSimilarityConfig();
        Collection<RetrievalResult> eval = NNScoringMethod.evaluateSimilarity(casebase.getCases(), query, simConfig);
        eval = SelectCases.selectTopKRR(eval, 5);
        System.out.println("Retrieved cases:");
        for (RetrievalResult nse : eval)
            System.out.println(nse);
    }
 
    @Generated(value = { "ColibriStudio" })
    @Override
    public void postCycle() throws ExecutionException {
        connector.close();
    }
 
    /**
     * Main method
     */
    @Generated(value = { "ColibriStudio" })
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CBRApplication cbrApp = new CBRApplication();
        try {
            cbrApp.configure();
            CBRCaseBase caseBase = cbrApp.preCycle();
           
            for(CBRCase c: caseBase.getCases())
                System.out.println(c);
           
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Eclipse is saying that "javax.annotation" is not accessible, there may be a problem with what JDK is being used to compile your code.  Are you expecting that your code requires a JDK 1.8 compiler?

The first thing to check is what Java Execution Environment name is associated with your project.  If you require JDK 1.8, then in Project Properties and Java Compiler, it should refer to "JavaSE-1.8" as the execution environment.

You should also check the definition of the Execution Environment itself. This is found in Eclipse Preferences->Java->InstalledJREs->ExecutionEnvironments .  If you click on "JavaSE-1.8", you should have one or more Java distributions in the list, and one of them should be checked, and the checked one should have "jdk" in the name, not "jre".

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependency

```
//..implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).